# Include related php from same server dynamically

Tags: php, html, regex, include, require

I have an html validator (PHP), that receives an URL as input, then loads the code and analyzes it.
 And for every html analyzed, there is an php file with variables that i must access, i cant modify these files one by one.
Througth regex i can get the original url and make it to the path of the php with the variables.
How can i access to these variable in my validator?
The point is, i cant include/require these files. What would be the possible solutions?

I tried adding one line to every config file(the ones that i need the variables), that would transform the variables to a json that i get throught javascript, but it aint the solution i need.

To get things clearer, ill try to explain how it (should) work.

I open the validator
Insert the url from the email i want to validate ex: server.com/email_number/email.php
In one tab of the validator, i get the config file ex: server.com/email_number/config/config.php
Theses datas are used for many purposes.

```
$url = $_GET['emktFile'];
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', $path);
$urlArray = parse_url($url);
unset($segments[count($segments) - 1]);
$requireUrl = $urlArray[scheme] . "://" . $urlArray[host] . implode("/", $segments) . "/config/emkt-config.php";

echo $requireUrl;
require_once $requireUrl;
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var emktConfig='" . json_encode($emktConfig) . "'</script>";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide some code samples? Use 4-space indenting to get preformatted text. (Or wrap in <code></code>.)

Comment: I hope the code ive put there helps, its the validator part that sould include de config php